# JavaScript: How to call a function stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm storing a piece of JavaScript Code inside a variable and I want to later call it like if it was a normal function, not using eveal().
Quite like a callback that a code library can execute.
What is the best way to achieve this?

I have tried

```
window[leaveCallback]();
```

and

```
eveal();
```

to call code from variables, but none of them worked for me.
I don't want use eveal() because of obvious security reasons

This is my variable:

```
var callback = (function() {
    alert('leave callback');
});
```

How can I execute the code Inside of this variable?

My goal is to simply call the code stored as a variable but I didn't get it to work so far.

I would be thankfull if someone explained how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: just `callback()` (a function call) should work. JavaScript has first order functions - they're just regular objects.

Comment: you can also use `call` or `apply` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: I checked MDN but i can't quite find the answer there

Comment: @dgeare if we're being pedant - you can also `Reflect.apply` or do a bunch of other stuff to invoke a function :D

Comment: “A function stored in a variable” is simply a function. You simply call it.

Answer (score 1):

Add parens after the variable name to call it . . .
In your example type: callback()

However, if the function defined is nested inside of another function this will not work as it will be in a closure and will only be callable from within the function that encloses it.

Answer (score 1):

If its a global function, just call it globally

```
window.callback();
```

or for short

```
callback();
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, if you declare `callback` in the global scope or you add it to the window object by

```
window.callback = function() { alert('leave callback'); }
```

you can just call it as `callback()` or `window.callback()`.

---

Bit of a longshot, but if you want to create a function which calls alert with a fixed argument, you probably want to do something like this:

```
 const alertWith = (message) => () => alert(message);
 window.leaveCallback = alertWith('leave callback');
```

This function `alertWith` is a so called *higher order function*. It returns another function whose scope contains the fixed binding `message -> 'leave callback'`

Have a look at the code snippet to see how you can make use of this pattern.

```js
const alertWith = (message) => () => alert(message);
window.leaveCallback = alertWith('leave callback');
  
leaveCallback();
```